# How to upload file to SharePoint using Graph API in C#.NET

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

Can anyone help to get C#.NET code to upload large files into SharePoint using Graph API.

Thank you and regards,
Rakesh

Comment: I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49776955/how-to-upload-a-large-document-in-c-sharp-using-the-microsoft-graph-api-rest-cal/59776567#59776567 but in that LargeFileUpload class definition is not given. If anyone know this please share.

Answer (score 0):

The answer in the linked question shows how to use the `LargeFileUpload` class that comes as part of the **Microsoft Graph C# SDK**.

You do not need to implement the class yourself.

[This link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/large-file-upload?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp) shows the C# code needed to use the SDK classes/functionality

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
 DriveItem file = await graphClient
  .Sites["IdSite"]
  .Drives["Id"]
  .Items["IdDrive"]]
  .ItemWithPath("nameFile")
  .Content
  .Request()
  .PutAsync<DriveItem>(stream);
```