# Graph API v5 upload file to sharepoint

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I have installed the Graph API v5 using c# and I am trying to follow the below examples of uploading a file to sharepoint. Seems like some of the methods do not exist anymore in the graph API v5.

1st code doesnt recognise Items

```
var uploadSession = await graphClient.Drive.Items["itemId"].ItemWithPath("SWEBOK.pdf").CreateUploadSession().Request().PostAsync();
```

doesnt recognise Root

```
var uploadedFile = client.Me.Drive.Root  
                              .ItemWithPath("smallfile.txt")  
                              .Content  
                              .Request()  
                              .PutAsync<DriveItem>(fileStream)  
                              .Result;
```

[Graph API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/large-file-upload?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp)

[Upload example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49776955/how-to-upload-a-large-document-in-c-sharp-using-the-microsoft-graph-api-rest-cal)

Anyone can refer me to documentation of how to upload using graph api v5.

Is it better to use a older version of Graph API instead of the version 5. Also is it better to use http client call instead of using the SDK libraries. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know `driveId` then you can access `MicrosoftGraphCreateUploadSession` this way

```
var uploadSessionBody = new Microsoft.Graph.Drives.Item.Items.Item.MicrosoftGraphCreateUploadSession.CreateUploadSessionPostRequestBody
{
    // Item = ...
};
var uploadSession = await _client.Drives["driveId"]
                             .Items["itemId"]
                             .ItemWithPath("SWEBOK.pdf")                
                             .MicrosoftGraphCreateUploadSession
                             .PostAsync(uploadSessionBody);
```

Upload file to your Root

```
var uploadedFile = await _client.Drives["Me"].Root
                          .ItemWithPath("smallfile.txt")
                          .Content
                          .PutAsync(fileStream);
```

Doc:

[Upgrade guide to v5](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/feature/5.0/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md)

Comment: Thanks was able to upload using suggested code. Although cannot get return file id of uploaded file as method doesnt return value.  await graphClient.Drives[drive.Id].Items[driveItem.Id].ItemWithPath("file.txt").Content.PutAsync(fileStream)

Comment: @JasonK Yes, it returns only Task. You need to make one extra call var newDriveItem = await graphClient.Drives[drive.Id].Items[driveItem.Id].ItemWithPath("file.txt").GetAsync(); Hope it will be fixed soon in SDK

Answer (score 1):

This process is documented at ["Upload large files using the Microsoft Graph SDKs"](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/main/concepts/sdks/large-file-upload.md).

First of, configure a `CreateUploadSessionPostRequestBody`

```
// Use properties to specify the conflict behavior
// in this case, replace
var uploadSessionRequestBody = new CreateUploadSessionPostRequestBody
{
    Item = new DriveItemUploadableProperties
    {
        AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior", "replace" }
        }
    }
};
```

Note that this class is apparently present in numerous namespaces. In my case the correct one was *Microsoft.Graph.Drives.Item.Items.Item.CreateUploadSession*, but YMMV.

[image: Possible locations of CreateUploadSessionPostRequestBody]

I needed to upload files to a specific directory, and thus used this code:

```
var uploadSession = await GraphServiceClient
    .Drives[driveId]
    .Items[folderId]
    .ItemWithPath(fileName)
    .CreateUploadSession
    .PostAsync(uploadSessionRequestBody);
```

If it is a large file, you need to do this in chunks:

```
int maxSliceSize = 320 * 1024 * 33; // ~10MB
var fileUploadTask = new LargeFileUploadTask<DriveItem>(uploadSession, fileStream, maxSliceSize);
```

And then you need to execute the upload:

```
var uploadResult = await fileUploadTask.UploadAsync(progress);
```

For completion, here are the `using`s at the top of my class which contains this code:

```
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Drives.Item.Items.Item.CreateUploadSession;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors;
```